# Pass data changes from modal back to child component

Tags: angular

My parent component has a child components: Child0 and Display.

Child 0 has one button that opens a modal where the user can select items from a list.
Display component has only a label and some text.

The UI flow:

1. The user clicks the button
2. A modal opens and displays some items in a grid
3. The user can select data by marking a checkbox in each row
4. The user closes the modal
5. The selected data is displayed in the Display component.

The selected data is stored in a service.

I am having issues showing the data in the Display component. When I look at the selected data in `ngOnInit` it is empty because the user hasn't selected anything yet. How do I update this component when the selected data changes?

Main App Component

```
<div class="row">     
  <child0-app (onSelectedData)="getSelectedData($event)"  [dataForm]="dataForm"></child0-app>     
</div>  
<div class="row">
   <app-display></app-display>
</div>
```

My Service

```
  public getSelectedData() {
    return this.selectedData;
  }

  public setSelectedData(selectedData: any[]) {
    this.selectedData = selectedData;
  }
```

GridComponent

```
 getCheckedItemList() {
    this.checkedList = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
       if (this.data[i].isSelected) {
        this.checkedList.push(this.data[i].Name);
      }
    }
   this.appService.setSelectedData(this.checkedList);
  }
```

DisplayComponent

```
 constructor(private service: AppService) {
    this.selectedData = this.service.getSelectedData();  
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-data-pass)

---Updated Answer---

Thanks @Vlad for helping me fix this.

For anyone else visiting this post. I used the below code in to subscribe and unsubscribe

```
private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

ngOnInit () { 
this.subscription.add(
 this.appService.selectedDataObservable.subscribe(selectedData => {
   console.log(selectedData);   
  }));
}  

 ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: you could use a service to share the data back with the parent component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-data-pass-vk51uv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I've updated the example to use the "Parent and children communicate via a service" pattern from the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

---

In short, you need some way to "listen" for changes to the data from the service. Angular includes the RxJS library for this situation. So, you need to create a `Subject` for emitting new values and an `Observable` for listening to changes.

Roughly, you'll end up with a service like:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {
    private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    public dataObservable = dataSubject.asObservable();

    public setData(data: any) {
        this.dataSubject.next(data);
    }
}
```

Other components can "send" data via:

```
this.dataService.setData(newData);
```

and get/listen for new data via:

```
this.dataService.dataObservable.subscribe(newData => {
    // Do Stuff
});
```

Because this uses a `BehaviorSubject`, which stores a "current value", any new subscribers will immediately run with the existing value AND listen for future changes.

---

**Things to note:**

1. Make sure to unsubscribe from the observable! Otherwise, you have introduced a memory leak. I'm partial to the `takeUntil` method from [this article](https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/).
2. "Listening" to changes is an asynchronous operation, so you may need to manually tell the component to update the view. I think [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) on change detection is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: thanks for the above it worked fine. I have one quick related question. If on any other page I want to just get the value of the data do I again have to use subscribe to get the data. Is there some get method that we can write in our service that would return the data that was selected. Its a related ques so thought of writing here, else would open a new post if required.

Comment: @karen I have updated the answer to use a `BehaviorSubject` which is intended for this situation - storing a "current value" AND being able to notify listeners of changes.